# In Firebase is it possible to see what nodes are being listened too & how do you do it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, sockets, firebase-realtime-database

## Background

I'm creating an app with firebase, react & node. I would like to lock or warn users if some paths are being listened by multiple connections.

## Question

Is it possible to get the number of connections looking at a particular part of the firebase?

## Example

If a user is at `someDocument/-LS_Ck1XNIyE6fm6QZbM` can i see if there's multiple connections at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. The Firebase Realtime Database can be used to build such a presence system. I recommend checking out the [sample presence system in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample), as well as the documentation on the same page on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and [how `onDisconnect` works](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I was looking in the wrong part of the docs. This looks good.

Comment: Maybe I understood the question wrong, but it seems to me that this solution will not provide the granularity implied in the original post.

Comment: Ah... I went of the title, which I now updated to reflect the actual question better. There is no way to track the current listeners. The closest I can think of is using the database profiler: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Comment: I quickly checked and the database profiler shows the data for all users connected to your database. It only shows it in aggregate, but you'd at least be able to get an idea of where most activity is.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question so that you want to limit reading data from some path to only limited number of users/connections.

There is no documented way of achieving this directly.

What I would suggest is to write restrictive database rules to prohibit direct access to this data. Then you could write a cloud function to implement this logic - administrative interface will circumvent the database rules.